# C# WinForms Application want to use asana API

Tags: c#, winforms, asana

I am trying to work with the asana API in my C# Windows Application and have several questions I'd like to ask.

1. When you register your application with asana, it wants to know APP NAME, APP URL, REDIRECT URL.  If it's a windows application, what values might I supply for the second two prompts?
2. When that is entered, you get a client id and a client secret.  Is this completely different than the apikey?  Is the former for OAuth and the latter for asana, or does asana work in conjunction with OAuth?
3. Basically I want to take a request like this: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks//stories?opt_pretty and get back in my application the same json I see when I issue the request in my browser.

Comment: You may need a small web app just to handle the oauth authentication stuff.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  But hoping not.  Because doesn't that mean the small web app would be authorized and not my windows app?    Because I wanted to keep going, I entered my company's website URL in APP URL, and the same for REDIRECT URL, which I was pretty sure wouldn't work, but it was something.  So I do have a client id and client secret I could try, but again, I'm not sure how to get started with that.

Comment: No. The web app needs to provide an assertion consumer service page where the Asana OAuth provider can return a token, but once that happens you can also let your desktop app use the token. But this isn't something I've needed to do a lot.

Comment: Can I use the PAT that I generated in asana?  Any code that I try gives me an error, The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.  Are there any complete code examples around?  I have been worrking on this for 6 days and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can provide localhost
2. You should definitely have a look at https://asana.com/developers
3. Your answer is there https://community.asana.com/t/can-a-windows-application-be-registered/23381 !

Good luck ;)